# Utilizing multiple database pool connections within multiple gunicorn workers

Tags: postgresql, flask, gunicorn, psycopg2, connection-pooling

I am using a **flask server** which initialises the app by creating 10 connections in **psycopg2 Connection Pool (using Postgres)**. My flask server receives 40 requests every second.

Every request uses 1 connection and takes approximately 5 seconds in the database. If a connection is not found in the connection pool, new connections are created.

**There is a limitation of 150 maximum  database connections on postgreSQL server**.  However, I am facing challenges in specifying the maximum number of connection in the connection pool . For the pool intialization, I use:

```
    app.config['pool'] = psycopg2.pool.ThreadedConnectionPool(
        10, 145,
        host = config["HOST"],
        database = config["DATABASE"],
        user = config["USER"],
        password = config["PASSWORD"]
    )
```

I know it may not be possible to share connections within multiple workers. What is the best practice to utilize these 150 connections across multiple workers?

Fo reference, my tech stack is flask + postgreSQL(on Azure). For deployment, i use gunicorn and nginx with flask.

Following is my gunicorn command-

```
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --worker-class=gevent --worker-connections=1000 --workers=3 --timeout=1000 manage:app
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to change the worker-class from gevent to sync or possibly gthread.
It is worth paying attention to the entry straight from the gunicorn documentation: "For full greenlet support applications might need to be adapted. When using, e.g., Gevent and Psycopg it makes sense to ensure psycogreen is installed and setup." (https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/design.html)